# SQL UNION or similar to supply missing absent rows?

Tags: sql

Given the two tables:

```
T_A

Key_A   A_1
1       A
2       B
3       C



T_B

Key_B    Key_A
10       1
10       2
10       3
20       1
20       2
30       1
```

I want to produce the following output set

```
T_X

Key_B   Key_A   A_1
10      1       A
10      2       B
10      3       C
20      1       A
20      2       B
20      3       C
30      1       A
30      2       B
30      3       C
```

Or whether ever a row in table T_B does not contain a value for column KEY_A supply/return that row as if it were there.

Is there any SQL to return this?

Comment: Do a JOIN, not a UNION.

Comment: Means firstly you need missing rows from T_B table, from above example,
20,3,C..
30,2,B..
30,3,C

And Union with present rows. is it correct?

Comment: So, you want to take each distinct `Key_B` column value from `T_B` and pair it with every row in `T_A` (and we can effectively ignore `Key_A` in `T_B`). Is that correct?

Comment: Use `FULL OUTER JOIN`. See more in: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp

Comment: If you join using 1=1 as joining criteria 
1) the distinct values of the Key_B in T_B and 2) all the rows of T_A, you will get what you show in your example...
select t_b.key_b,t_a.key_a, t_a.a_1 from (select distinct t_b.key_b 
from t_b) t_b inner join (select t_a.key_a, t_a.a_1 from t_a) t_a   
on 1=1

Comment: you should use `full outer join` for your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement

> Or whether ever a row in table T_B does not contain a value for column KEY_A supply/return that row as if it were there.

means that you return a row if a value is there - or if it isn't there. This can be reduced to returning a value regardless and not even checking. This makes things easy as you can perform a `cross join`, which returns every possible combination of the two tables.

The following will give you the result you want:

```
select distinct T_B.Key_B, T_A.Key_A, T_A.A_1
from T_B
cross join T_A
```

but it would possibly be more efficient, and clearer what you are doing, to get all `T_B.Key_B` and then join that to the other table, giving:

```
select sq.Key_B, T_A.Key_A, T_A.A_1
from (select distinct Key_B from T_B) sq
cross join T_A
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use inner join:-

```
   select T_A.A_1,T_B.Key_B,T_B.Key_A 
   from T_A inner join T_B
   on T_A.Key_A=T_B.Key_A
```

see on this:-    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1673/8

Comment: The OP has provided an expected result set in the question and your fiddle doesn't produce it.

Comment: According to SQL FIDDLE this simply returns the rows from T_B